# How to find out what load the server will sustain and how to develop a highly loaded project?

Tags: php, django

There is a server with such parameters:

Operating system:
Debian 7.11 x86
Memory RAM:
1024 MB
SSD memory:
30000 MB
CPU:
2x2.8 Ghz

I want to develop a social network project. Ability to search by certain parameters, send messages, add photos, publish entries to the wall. While this is the maximum. I'm interested in how much the server can handle, how to optimize for this site, and at what load will have to distribute the site to several servers, and most importantly, how to do it. This should be taken into account immediately at the beginning of writing, or to re-design the project will be easy?
At the beginning of the project there will be about 1000 visitors, in the future I plan about 5000. I wonder which server should be, how many servers, etc., because I do not know about large projects.

Comment: Hi, I am reviewing your post. The SO community values when you show your own efforts, so you might want to add some code. Please check here on how to ask good questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask